# Parse HTML5 with xmllint invalid tag

Tags: html, tidy, xmllint

I'm trying to parse html5 with xmllint, and it's generating errors on certain tags. To make sure it's valid I piped the output through tidy first, but it generated the same errors. I only want to extract the text. Is there any way to read these invalid tags?

command:

```
echo $s | tidy -o | xmllint --html --xpath 'the xpath to be parsed'
```

error output:

```
-:178: HTML parser error : Tag svg invalid "21">
```

xmllint version:

```
xmllint: using libxml version 20904
```

Comment: I have same problem. Xmllint continue parsing. These messages are on stderr. Redirection help me `2>/dev/null` Not nice I know